# Vagrant - VM não sobe ao adicionar uma forwarded_port

Tags: redes, vagrant, virtualbox, linux

Fiz a instalação de uma VM usando o Vagrant com a ISO debian/jessie64, funcionou normal, dou o up na VM ela sobe lindamente, ao entrar no SSH, tudo certo, mas quando eu vou adicionar uma nova porta, ela não sobe mais.
Meu arquivo "original" `Vagrantfile` esta assim:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
end
```

Mas quando eu adiciono a linha:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

A VM não sobe mais, mostra a seguinte mensagem:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\sandbox>vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'debian/jessie64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `initialize': O endereþo solicitado nÒo Ú vßlido no contexto. - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 8080 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `block in is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `block in catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:19:in `is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:248:in `port_check'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `[]'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `block in handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:257:in `block in with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:98:in `handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:78:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:39:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:235:in `block in with_target_vms'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:229:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:229:in `with_target_vms'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:37:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

Obs: Estou usando:
Windows 10
Vagrant 1.9.3
PuTTY
ebian/jessie64 - com algumas instalações como: git, ruby, php..
VirtualBox 5.1.14 r112924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[É um bug do Vagrant 1.9.3](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3/issues/106). A recomendação, por ora, é fazer *downgrade* do Vagrant para a versão 1.9.2.

Para Windows e Linux, [use este link](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.2/).

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, não tive mais o problema ao adicionar uma nova porta, mas acabei tendo outros dois problemas, vou abrir um novo tópico para documentar de uma melhor forma..